# Merge mysql columns to rows

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have a table with the following structure:

```
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID  |  FEATURE1  |  FEATURE2  |  FEATURE3  |  FEATURE4  |
+-----+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1  |  red       |  blue      |  black     |  grey      |
|  2  |  yellow    |            |            |            |
|  3  |  orange    |  red       |  green     |  golden    |
|  4  |  orange    |  grey      |  blue      |            |
```

What I would like to do is query the table and return all possible features for use in an autocomplete call. I need the query to only return unique values.

```
SELECT (FEATURE1, FEATURE2, FEATURE3, FEATURE4, FEATURE5) FEATURE
FROM products
WHERE `FEATURE` LIKE 'gr%\'
```

My desired output would be:

```
+----------+
| FEATURE  |
+----------+
|  green   |
|  grey    |
```

Comment: concat all columns and filter with 'gr%'.

Comment: Return unique values or distinct values ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, you can use `UNION` to combine all columns in a single row.

```
SELECT  * 
FROM
(
    SELECT FEATURE1 FEATURE FROM TableName
    UNION
    SELECT FEATURE2 FEATURE FROM TableName
    UNION
    SELECT FEATURE3 FEATURE FROM TableName
    UNION
    SELECT FEATURE4 FEATURE FROM TableName
) sub
WHERE   FEATURE LIKE 'gr%'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2653a/1)

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect. I have a few questions. Should I be adding indexes on the FEATURE columns?

Comment: Should I be adding indexes on the FEATURE columns?
How does MYSQL know to select DISTINCT values?
Should I really be creating a separate table to store the features if I wish this table to hold a large number of records?